# Changing default access denied path when integrating Azure AD into an ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to change the default access denied path when authorization is denied when using Azure AD.

For example, when working with Microsoft's example of "Integrating Azure AD into an ASP.NET Core web app" seen here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/

The article reference an example project on GitHub see here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore.

I am having difficulties configuring the options inside `Startup.cs` to change the default controller/method for access denied (which is "Account/AccessDenied").

Can someone please help provide the required changes to the github sample project above so that an unauthorized user is taken to a different path when they are denied authorization other than the default  "Account/AccessDenied"?

**UPDATE**: I added what @Brad suggested in the startup prior (and again now) in my project, but it didn't change, and I'm still being directed to "Account/AccessDenied"... can you think of any other setting that might govern this?

For my project (the automatically created ASP.NET Core Web Application - Web Application (Model-View-Controller) using **Work or School Accounts Authentication** in Visual Studio 2017), which differs from the example project. I am referencing the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` and setting up my AzureAD in the following way (please note using `.AddAzureAD` and not `.AddAzureAd`):

```cs
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies  
    // is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

services
    .AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home";
     });
```

Comment: How are you determining that this doesn't work?  The `options.AccessDeniedPath` setting is used when your app returns a `ForbidResult` (403) from an action method.

Comment: @Brad I am determining this by adding a policy for a group my user doesn't have,  and then decorating the controller with that authorization and required policy, and accessing that controller. I am being redirected to  "Account/AccessDenied" instead of the expected "/Home". I have to clarify that when adding your suggestion to the example github project referenced it is working the way you described, but when I add it to my project that defines the azure active directory slightly differently (details in my update above) then it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use the simple overload of `AddAzureAd` that only takes an action lambda, the library automatically adds a Cookie scheme for you, but it adds it under the `AzureAdDefaults.CookieScheme' name (not sure why) with it's own set of options. If you try to use any normal method to customize the cookie options, it will never get called because you're trying to configure the wrong cookie scheme.

Instead, you can configure the cookie options for the Azure AD custom cookie scheme once it's been added, like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme, options => options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/NoAuth");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!, I was searching in the AspNetCore github repo and found the file CookieOptionsConfiguration file and I never figured out how to change those values, yeah, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Microsoft.Identity.Web package, like in the latest MVC core VS templates, you'll have this line:

```
services.AddSignIn(Configuration);
```

in which case you'll have to do add this:

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
            options => options.AccessDeniedPath = "/your/path");
```

Answer (score -1):

This is configured in the cookie authentication options.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddAzureAd(...)
    .AddCookie(options => 
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/path/to/unauthorized";
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't actually change the access denied behavior (though it seems like it should.)