# Unable to change "access denied path" when using Azure AD authentication without Identity

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm unable to change the default "access denied" path of `Account/AccessDenied` when using Azure AD authentication. What settings do I need to configure to override this? 
I've looked at several articles including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833380/changing-default-access-denied-path-when-integrating-azure-ad-into-an-asp-net-co) but no success yet.

My current `startup.cs` code looks like this -

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/AccessDenied";
                    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ctx =>
                          {
                              var requestPath = ctx.Request.Path;
                              if (requestPath.StartsWithSegments("/Account"))
                              {
                                  ctx.Response.Redirect("/Error/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=" + requestPath + ctx.Request.QueryString);
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  ctx.Response.Redirect("/Login?ReturnUrl=" + requestPath + ctx.Request.QueryString);
                              }
                              return Task.CompletedTask;
                          }
                    };
                });
```

This redirect doesn't work and the event is not fired either. I've tried setting cookie options using `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` but that doesn't work either (documentation says it's for identity module anyways).

What am I missing?
My asp.net project is using .net core 2.2 and it's template was generated from the Visual Studio template.

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55733041/425736 and see if that helps.